# Using select query on access database

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

first i was trying to use execute with select query which returns error type mismatch. then after reading some toturials i found out that openrecordset is the trick.

now i am having issue with openrecordset as it is just returning the query and not the selected value. below is my code:

```
Dim sql As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

      ' this will loop through each cell in column I until end
    For x = 1 To NumRows

       sql = "select Email from Salesforce where ID =" & ActiveCell.Value
       Set rs = oDB.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = rs
```

so `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = sql` is just inserting the select Email from Salesforce where ID equals ActiveCell.Value

Comment: Rs now is the full query. To get the value you want, you have to type it like `rs.Fields("nameofyourfield").Value` so in your case, should work `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = rs.Fields("Email").Value`

Comment: thanks a ton foxfire. can you also help dealing with not record set error. i am trying something like this . If (rs.EOF) Then ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select Else ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value = rs.Fields("Email").Value

Comment: Isn't `ActiveCell.Offset` Excel referencing? Access has records and fields, not cells. Exactly what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Did what I say worked for you? then we should post it as answer, and then you should open a new question with your new problem.

Comment: it worked foxfire. can be closed now

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).CopyFromRecordset rs
```